# how to add phone number next to my account

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, layout, blocks

I would like to add support phone number before my account in top link.  Please help step by step in including path.  I am a beginner.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a static block.create static block from backend CMS > Static block.Add new block and under it add your support contact number.and call this static block using the following code

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('header-contact-no')->toHtml(); ?>
```

header-contact-no is my cms block identifier